# How do I completely clean out NServiceBus?

Tags: .net, ravendb, msmq, nservicebus

I am trying to get NServiceBus to clean itself out completely in a test environment (as it appears to keep on trying to process missing timeouts). I would then like to re-install. However I am unable to get my NServiceBus program to start normally after the reinstall due to data persisting from before the uninstall.

What I've tried so far:

- Uninstall ServiceControl, NServiceBus.Dtc, NServiceBus.PerfCounters, NServiceBus.MSMQ, NServiceBUs.RavenDB all using chocolately
- Deleted C:\ProgramData\Particular\ServiceControl
- Deleted "C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software"
- Deleted "C:\Program Files\NServiceBus.Persistence.v4"
- Deleted all private message queues

**Configuration:**

NServiceBus is installed on the test environment using chocolately. I use automated deployment to transfer files to the test server, install as a windows service and start the service.

The host is configured using:

```
   <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyNamespace.Messages" Endpoint="MyNamespace.Service" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

The only other configuration that I have is in the endpoint config:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization, IWantCustomLogging
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            //structuremap
            Configure.With().StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container);

            //log4net
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => XmlConfigurator.Configure());

        }
    }
```

Comment: A couple of questions:

* Which NServiceBus version are you using?
* Where are you storing Timeouts?
* Can you share your endpoint configuration?

Comment: I've added some edits.

Comment: Can you help with some log files?